# .htaccess: rewrite url from domain_a.com/#something to domain_b.com/#something without changing visible url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite URLs from domain_a.de to domain_b.de/$1

More specifically, I want the browser to keep showing domain_a plus keep hash tags after the domain itself:

e.g. domain_a.de/#events ---> domain_b.de/#events

I'm trying the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain_a.de/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain_b.de/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

I thought this should do the trick. But instead, I keep getting:

```
"Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server."
```

Is there something wrong with my .htaccess or could it be that the server doesn't even support mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to answer this myself:

The problem actually only occurred when browsing www.doman_a.de.

After adding

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain_a.de/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain_b.de/$1 [P]
```

for redirecting visitors for www.* everything worked fine.